# How to generate a Audio sound Output on Nexys ddr 4 FPGA

Tags: audio, verilog, fpga

I want try to using Nexys 4 to generate car sound. Do i need to store the sound in ROM? what is the step to create a sound. I am using the verilog. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog

Comment: @dave_59 Verilog is unfortunately a topic which is both present on "stackoverflow.com" and on "electronics.stackexchange.com". On both sites the same topics are discussed.

Comment: @MartinRosenau The point is that people muddle the concept of designing an FPGA with coding in a programming language. Stack overflow is for code and language issues. Electronics is for hardware issues. Verilog straddles both because it is a language for describing hardware. This question has nothing to do with the code itself

Answer (score 0):

The Nexys 4 board does not contain an audio codec but it contains a simple lowpass (or bandpass) filter creating a sound output from a PWM signal.

Your programming challenge is to create a PWM signal whose duty cycle represents the current level of the sound output signal.

I would think about the following pseudo-code (here C-like, not Verilog like):

```
signed int levelAccu = 0;

on_Every_Clock_Edge()
{
    int level = getCurrentSoundLevel();
    levelAccu += level;
    if(levelAccu > 0)
    {
        setOutputPin(HIGH);
        levelAccu -= MAX_LEVEL;
    }
    else
    {
        setOutputPin(LOW);
        levelAccu -= MIN_LEVEL;
    }
}
```

While:

`getSoundLevel()` represents the current desired "level" of the sound output. (The value of the current sample if you use sampled sound.)

`MAX_LEVEL` and `MIN_LEVEL` are the maximum and minimum values of the "level". Example: If you want to play sound which is stored as 8-bit signed values you have `MAX_LEVEL=127` and `MIN_LEVEL=-128`.

The register `levelAccu` should have 1 or 2 bits more than the `level`.

Note that the clock edges must be much faster than the sample rate of the audio.

> Do I need to store the sound in ROM?

Depends on which kind of sound you want to create.

If you want to play recorded sound samples you'll have to store them in some memory (RAM, ROM...).

If you want to generate sound programmatically (such as sine waves) you don't have to store them.

**By the way**

Your question is not Verilog specific but it is more related to FPGAs in common and to the circuits close to the FPGA.

For this reason "electronics.stackexchange.com" should really be the better place for such questions.